# Android Studio button material stop activity when icon change

Tags: java, android-studio

I am new to android, I have a MaterialButton and I would like its icon to change, but the activity suddenly stops, I do not see where the problem comes from, I show you the code, it is an audio player. (if you need all code of class I send u, inform me)

xml code :

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_play_music"
        style="@style/myTheme.btn_last_music"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_10"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
        />
```

onCreate :

```
btnPlay = (MaterialButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_play_music);
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlay.setTag(5);
```

method to play music :

```
public void playIfItemClicked(SearchMusic lm, int i) {
mediaPlayer.reset();
Uri u = lm.getListMusic().get(i).getUri();
InteractiveMusic intMus = new InteractiveMusic(mediaPlayer, u);
try {
    intMus.playMusic();
    btnPlay.setIconTintResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: When the activity stops, what does the error say. Have you seen the Logcat? Have you tried to debug the activity? Switch your Logcat from Verbose to Warn and look for error messages and lets see.

Comment: thx u, I was able to solve the problem it was a small mistake on my part, thank you for your advice I would think about it next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i have find the solution,

it's this line :

```
btnPlay.setIconTintResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
```

change to :

```
btnPlay.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
```